# XCode4 - where to look for sqlite file created by core data

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, xcode4

I have just started using core data. I want to setup a pre-populated db. I read somewhere that core data creates a sqlite file when a core data app is run. I don't know where to look for it though.

I followed the instructions over on this [blog](http://ablogontech.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/using-a-pre-populated-sqlite-database-with-core-data-on-iphone-os-3-0/) but did not find the sqlite file over the location specified directory `/Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Application/<Application GUID>/Documents/<database name.sqlite>` nor in the application directory.

here is my code for persistentCoordinator.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString *storePath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"coredata.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"coredata" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those files are in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[SDK version]/Applications/[App GUID]/Documents` for me, both for Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.

If you have multiple SDKs, make sure to look in all the different SDK version directories for your app.

Comment: How to know the **App GUID** ?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was in whatMuregSaid/[Application Guid]/Library/Application Support/[AppName]/filename.sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. In your `applicationDocumentsDirectory` function in AppDelegate.swift add this code:

   `let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)`

   `// Look for this in the console, this will print out the location of the sqlite database, which you can then open with an SQLite viewer`

   `print("urls.last \(urls.last)")`
2. Look for this in the console, this will print out the location of the sqlite database, open your terminal and `open whatever_the_location_path_was`
3. Download SQLite viewer http://sqlitebrowser.org/
4. Right click the yourapp.sqlite file in the folder, choose Open With sqlitebrowser that you downloaded

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you little more

1. /Users/Username/ then press cmd+shift+G  and write /Users/Username/Library, Now you will see Library folder after it  go to Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1(or 7.1-64)/Applications/F84D4CC8-326E-4A2E-8A37-F1A755D6FCC4/Documents 
   you will see three file and one is .sqlite file.
2. To see structure and other information  of this sqlite file , the most efficient way is use SQLITE MANAGER(add on of firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) add it and then click  TOOL .