# Convert from Core Data to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, core-data

I have an already existing DB that was written in Core Data for an iPhone application that I'm trying to make cross-platform.

is there a way to export or convert from Core Data to SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an external ORM and created my own version of the DB on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but these links might help:

http://coderslike.us/2009/06/11/how-to-find-that-sqlite-file-behind-your-coredata/

http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/05/16/locating-core-datas-sqlite-database/

[XCode4 - where to look for sqlite file created by core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507395/xcode4-where-to-look-for-sqlite-file-created-by-core-data)

[Does core data create a SQLite database file automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901694/does-core-data-create-a-sqlite-database-file-automatically?rq=1)