# how to open the core data model created sqlite file to view entries

Tags: ios, core-data

the file is located at 
/Users/anand/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/66751FC8-AC4E-4D62-93F1-DAAB2F3D67BF/Documents

but i cannot navigate to this path in the finder as the Library folder does not appear under /Users/anand listing.

I can list it in the terminal, but then how do i open the sqlite file to view the entries stored.

Please note I would like to use a visual tool and not the command line sqlite3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26838748/3767017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate to this folder by pressing `cmd + shift + G` in Finder and typing in the path. Or you can use the `open <path>` terminal command.

There are several visual SQLite clients for the Mac. See this question for details: [Mac SQLite editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor). My personal favorite is [SQLIteManager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlitemanager/id412443832?mt=12).

Answer (score 2):

If you are in finder, click `Go`, then hold `alt` key and Library will appear

I use [Sqlite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Comment: Another option for viewing is the free Firefox addon at https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/